# server 2016 unable to add roles or features after making server a domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am having a problem i cannot install roles or features at all.

I installed windows server 2016 standard with desktop as a hardware machine not virtual joined existing domain installed anti-virus software a few tools then i added active directory role promoted to domain controller then made it the primary controller.

I noticed that windows server backup was not installed by default and tried to add it. 
It failed using both GUI wizard and with PS i also tried to add IIS server role with GUI and get the same error this is the output from PS ive tried using the -source switch leading to the dell install DVD and the error doesn't change been searching internet for a week not much information out there on server 2016 any help would be appreciated

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.MOSBAUGH> install-windowsfeature -name windows-server-backup
install-windowsfeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701
At line:1 char:1
+ install-windowsfeature -name windows-server-backup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo         : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWind
  owsFeatureCommand

Success Restart Needed Exit Code     Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------     --------------
False No           Failed       {}
```

here are the logs

> 2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Exec: 1 deployments need bulk staging
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 CSI    00000008@2017/3/16:15:25:19.195 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\csd_locking.cpp(200): Error STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING originated in function CCSDirectTransaction::LockComponent expression: (null)
>   [gle=0x80004005]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170316151828.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170316143828.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170316135830.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170316131828.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20170316123827.log to WER report.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Not able to add poqexec.log to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING #1938# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 0 of 1 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd015000c]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 CSI    0000000a (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING) #1786# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_PinDeployment(Flags = 0, a = Microsoft-Windows-BLB-Deployment-LanguagePack, version 10.0.14393.0, arch amd64, culture [l:5]'de-DE', nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, cb = (null), s = (null), rid = 'Microsoft-Windows-BLB-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0.WindowsServerBackup', rah = (null), manpath = (null), catpath = (null), ed = 0, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073701]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update: Microsoft-Windows-BLB-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0.WindowsServerBackup from file: (null) [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Failed to bulk stage deployment manifest and pin deployment for package:Microsoft-Windows-BLB-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~fr-FR~10.0.14393.0 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Started persisting state of packages
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Completed persisting state of packages
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CSI    0000000b@2017/3/16:15:25:19.305 CSI Transaction @0x27e7fd8feb0 destroyed
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain complete.
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0, status: 0x80073701, failure source: Resolve, start state: Installed, target state: Installed, client id: DISM Package Manager Provider
>
> 2017-03-16 08:25:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9420 TID=8584 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
>   2017-03-16 08:25:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9420 TID=8584 Loading Provider from location C:\Windows\TEMP\9635013C-AFB3-4CA4-A413-6716C64C4A10\CbsProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
>   2017-03-16 08:25:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9420 TID=8584 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Windows\TEMP\9635013C-AFB3-4CA4-A413-6716C64C4A10\CbsProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
>   2017-03-16 08:25:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=9420 TID=8584 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
>   2017-03-16 08:25:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 Finished initializing the CbsConUI Handler. - CCbsConUIHandler::Initialize
>   2017-03-16 08:25:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 CBS is being initialized for online use. More information about CBS actions can be located at: %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log - CDISMPackageManager::Initialize
>   2017-03-16 08:25:15, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::RefreshInstanceAndLock
>   2017-03-16 08:25:16, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 Initiating Changes on Package with values: 5, 7 - CDISMPackage::Internal_ChangePackageState
>   2017-03-16 08:25:18, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8012  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80073701) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80073701)
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9420 TID=8584 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x80073701)
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 Failed to process features change - CEnableDisableFeatureCommandObject::InternalExecute(hr:0x80073701)
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 InternalExecute failed - CBaseCommandObject::Execute(hr:0x80073701)
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Error                 DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 CEnableDisableFeatureCommandObject internal execution failed - DismEnableDisableFeatureInternal(hr:0x80073701)
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Exit DismEnableDisableFeatureInternal - DismEnableDisableFeatureInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Enter DismGetLastErrorMessageInternal - DismGetLastErrorMessageInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Exit DismGetLastErrorMessageInternal - DismGetLastErrorMessageInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Enter DismDeleteInternal - DismDeleteInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Leave DismDeleteInternal - DismDeleteInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Enter DismCloseSessionInternal - DismCloseSessionInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Input parameters: Session: 2 - DismCloseSessionInternal
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 GetReferenceCount hr: 0x0 - CSessionTable::RemoveSession
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Refcount for DismSession= 2s 0 - CSessionTable::RemoveSession
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=9896 Successfully enqueued command object - CCommandThread::EnqueueCommandObject
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 ExecuteLoop: CommandQueue signaled - CCommandThread::ExecuteLoop
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 Successfully dequeued command object - CCommandThread::DequeueCommandObject
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 ExecuteLoop: Cancel signaled - CCommandThread::ExecuteLoop
>   2017-03-16 08:25:19, Info                  DISM   API: PID=3560 TID=1232 Leave CCommandThread::ExecuteLoop - CCommandThread::ExecuteLoop

Also it did updates yesterday they worked except for KB4013429 but it says the system is up to date

Comment: That's one I haven't seen before.  Go to %windir%\logs, and search in both cbs\cbs.log and dism\dism.log for ", error" (a comma space error) and add the most recent ones to your post, and 10 to 15 lines before and after.

Comment: @Mitch I know this is a silly question but is your Windows Update service running? It looks like it is reaching out to pull in some updates which it uses for installation just like back in Server 2008 days where it downloaded the installer for WSUS. Also did you try an sfc /scannow ?

Comment: That happend for me too few months ago. I installed NPS on my Server 2016 and made reboot. After reboot I wasn't able to install any roles and features via GUI nor PowerShell and it got more stanger cause few roles and features was missing from the list. On top of that Server Manager didn't even detect that AD DS was running on this virtual machine but manually checking AD/DNS resulted in successful output. I didn't got time debug issue in depth so I ended up just reinstalling Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this as follows:

I had the same experience with a new Dell server, loaded with Server 2016 with English, Japanese, French, Spanish, and Korean languages pre-installed.

Something went south and the language pack for Korean was not installed.  But the OS registry entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect` were created and orphaned.

When I tried to install some roles or features the error

> The referenced assembly could not be found.

was returned, due to the install looking for those referenced language entries that were not installed.

If you open powershell and run `lpksetup`, click on uninstall display languages and see which languages are installed.  I uninstalled all extra languages, one at a time.

Now you can try the install and when it fails goto `c:\windows\logs\cbs`.  Throw the CBS log into notepad and search for the text error.  Look for a line with

> error CSI    0000000a (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING)

the next line with, say

> Info CBS    Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update:

might have the name of the package that is missing.

If you're lucky, it will have a language code EN, ES, ko-KR, etc...

That's the language package that has been orphaned!

Now the fun part. You can

1. Delete all the entries in the registry, a lot of them!

or

2. Download the language pack or language pack ISO for 2016 server and install the language pack for the offending language using the `lpksetup` utility and the cab for the language.  Then use `lpksetup` again to remove the language.

Done!

Try your role or feature install again.

This is how I ended up fixing the problem.

Took me a while to find the proper language pack for Server 2016, the windows 10 packs — no work-y...  Had to download an ISO from the Microsoft licensing site to get the correct one!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

i had to remove all reference values not keys containing fr-FR and de-DE values from the key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect] and i am now able to add roles and features neither of the language packs were installed on the server.

Comment: Micth, How did you find the references to the languages ​in that option? To delete all. Please. I have the same problem. Install-windowsfeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701
At line:1 char:1 + Install-windowsfeature AD-Domain-Services
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMA

Answer (score 1):

Finally it fixed! Here's how:

- Run `C:\Windows\System32\lpksetup.exe`
- Chose "Uninstall"
- Uninstall (nearly) all displayed languages (eg French, German, Korean, Japanese)
- This will take a while

After uninstalling those additional languages, open the Server Manager again, click the Roles & Features wizard and install the telnet feature. This doesn't require any registry editing and server restart.

Comment: Hi, @Ritesh! I know it's been a while, but can you provide any information about why language packs were related to your issue? I want to know if I'm having a similar issue or not. Thanks!