# server 2016 unable to add roles or features (not language issues)

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to install Hyper-V on a window Server 2016, but it is failing with an error "The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701"

Looking in the CBS log, I find the following error:

> CSI 00000009 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING #137412# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 0 of 1 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd015000c]
>
> CSI 0000000a (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING) #137260# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_PinDeployment(Flags = 0, a = f6094af0714877f03ea48f7a77328677, version 10.0.14393.1613, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, cb = (null), s = (null), rid = 'Package_1541_for_KB4038782~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.10.4038782-3713_neutral', rah = '2', manpath = (null), catpath = (null), ed = 0, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073701]
>
> CBS Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update: Package_1541_for_KB4038782~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.10.4038782-3713_neutral from file: (null) [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]

I've checked for issues with language packs ([server 2016 unable to add roles or features after making server a domain controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/838588/server-2016-unable-to-add-roles-or-features-after-making-server-a-domain-control/928883#928883)), and English is the only one installed.

I've also run the following:

- Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
- Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
- Dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /analyzecomponentstore
- Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /restoreHealth
- sfc.exe /scannow

A few issues where fixed, but nothing that seems related.

I think the issue is with KB4038782, but this appears to be superseded, and I cannot find a copy to download.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue. First of all you should try to install the latest cumulative update for Windows Server 2016 by downloading it manually from Microsoft: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5008601

Then, try again.

If it's still not working, you can try the workaround shown in [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/when-trying-to-install-updates-from-windows-update-you-might-receive-updates-failed-there-were-problems-installing-some-updates-but-we-ll-try-again-later-with-errors-0x80073701-0x800f0988-e74b3505-f054-7f15-ec44-6ec0ab15f3e0)

> When trying to install updates from Windows Update you might receive "Updates Failed, There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later" with one of the following errors:
>
> 0x80073701
>
> 0x800f0988
>
> ### Workaround
>
> [...]
> Type or copy and paste the following command into the Command Prompt window:
> `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`

Answer (score 0):

Server Manager GUI failed for me with empty error,

`Get-Package` failed with same
*The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701*
and  *DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand*

`dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`
seems had no effect either,

but instead
`Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:*`
finally worked. Detailed example and description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/enable-update-mdav-to-latest-ws?view=o365-worldwide).