# Windows Server 2019 can't install RemoteAccess - missing assembly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 datacenter (v1809) installed. I need to add Windows feature "RemoteAccess". I have tried installing it both from "Add Roles and Features Wizard" and through Powershell: "Install-Windows-Feature RemoteAccess". And both failed with error message saying missing assembly. Can I get any help?

[image]

Here is my CBS log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfKmzAxiM9TK7Ku1tuxK4HJVjua0XoTg/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: I said Windows server 2019

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a PowerShell problem, the same error (0x80073701) will be logged when using the Server Manager, too.

The most common problem causing this error is one of the installed language(s) on the machine.

The "works everytime" solution is to reinstall the OS. You can perform an ‘in-place upgrade’ which means running setup again from your installation media.  You will have to reinstall some of your programs but you will not loose your data files.

If you want to check if you can avoid reinstalling the OS, the registry key for reference assemblys is here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackageDetect
```

You can also check out this [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/838588/server-2016-unable-to-add-roles-or-features-after-making-server-a-domain-control) thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have successfully installed RemoteAccess on my server. I got the working solution from a Sysnative thread.